# Tomcat SES Friendly URLs Beneath Root (Lucee/Railo)

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, railo, lucee

I have an Tomcat/Lucee (Railo) setup and I'm trying to devise a way to get friendly URLs to work beneath the root.  Currently the Tomcat servlet-mapping is configured as:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<url-pattern>/index.cfml/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But it will only work if the index.cfm is in the root of the website.  I'd like a single configuration method so that I can use the following without having to make a specific servlet-mapping entry for each one:

```
/subDirectory1/index.cfm/main
/subDirectory2/index.cfm/main
```

Is this possible?  Perhaps using UrlRewriteFilter (tuckey)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat does not allow for multiple wildcards in a *servlet-mapping* *url-pattern*.  Adobe created their own fork of Tomcat to allow for this use case.

This may not be the answer you want, but without moving the *index.cfm* to the root and using the rewrite module to rewrite **/subDirectory1/index.cfm/main** to **/index.cfm/subDirectory1/main** (or some variant) and adjusting your code to suit, you will not be able to get away without editing your configuration for each subdirectory.